# MatDialog Child Closes Parent MatDialog

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-material, material-design

I have a dialog that is used as popup window form.  When user gets error the dialog pops up a smaller dialog with error message and OK button.

Clicking OK closes both matDialog windows.

How can I get it to just close its self and not its parent?

Parent =

```
<ng-template #dialogRef let-data>
```

Child =

```
this.dialog.open(ErrorDialogComponent, { data: message });
```

I have tried using different scopes, but OK seems to close all dialog windows.

Comment: In material design, you are not supposed to have more than one 'elevated' component - so having one dialog open over another is a no-no. Hide the first dialog then re-open when you close the second one, or use one dialog and replace the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can close a dialog programmatically with:

```
constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MyComponentToClose>){}


closeComponent(){
   this.dialogRef.close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This worked for me, though it's a slight workaround:

```
<button class="btn" mat-dialog-close="">Close</button>
```